# How do I stub out a value being tested in an unless statement?

Tags: ruby, rspec

So say for example I have something like this:

```
unless some_variable
  *stuff*
end
```

Is there a way to stub out some_variable to return false?

Comment: Your test is pointless, as far as I know and you have shown.

Comment: So this might make for a simpler question.. when calling unless some_variable, it's just checking if some_variable is nil, right? And if it isn't nil it executes the code inside the block?

Answer (score 0):

Depends from where you get the variable. It's hard to answer, as you code (and variable) is hanging in vacuum. You would usually control they way `some_variable` is defined:

```
def create
  some_variable = MyModel.active?

  unless some_variable
    # ..
  end
end
```

If you are using RSpec you could:

```
allow(MyModel).to receive('active?').and_return(false)
```

Here you preconditioned your variable to be false. I know it's poor example, but it's just to make a point.

Other case is when your variable is a method argument. In that case you would just call the method while passing `false` as and argument.